# Residue of $g(z)g'(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: Problem]

I know how to use the residue theorem and the winding number to find the residue of $f$, but I have no idea how to relate the residue of $g$ to that of $g\cdot g'$, especially without knowing anything about the order of the poles.

Comment: Well spotted. Adding $1/z^2$ to $g$ doesn't change any of the hypotheses, but it definitely changes the quantity to be computed (in general).

Comment: @GregMartin do you mean adding $\frac{1}{(z \pm 1)^2}?$

Comment: That's right, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** We can apply a substitution write
$$
\int_{\gamma} g(z)g'(z)\,dz= 
\int_{g(\gamma)} u\,du
$$
Of course, the function $\phi(u) = u$ is entire.